# Python 3 - way to interact with a web page

Tags: python, web, python-3.x

I have experience with reading and extracting html source 'as given'(via urllib.request), but now I would like to perform browser-alike actions(like filling a form, or selecting a value from the option menu) and then, of course, read a resulting html code as usual. I did come across some modules that seemed promising, but turned out not supporting Python 3.
So, I'm here asking for a name of library/module that does the wanted, or pointing to a solution within standard libraries if it's there and I failed to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually many websites (like Twitter, facebook or Wikipedia) provide their API's to let developers hook into their app and perform activities programmatically. For what so ever web site you wish to perform activities through code, just look for their API support.

In case you need to do web scraping, you can use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org). But it only has support upto python 2.7.x. Anyways, you can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for HTTP client and [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for HTML parsing.

Comment: I'm already using BS, and as for 'requests', I'm gonna learn about it and try to combine it with BS. Thanks for your reccomendation, sounds like it might come useful.